# How to Record line breaks in google translate imacros

Tags: imacros, google-translate

I have a text which I want to translate from german to english

here is the code

```html
CODE: SELECT ALL
VERSION BUILD=8970419 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=https://translate.google.com/#de/en
' fill the area with some text to translate
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TEXTAREA FORM=ID:gt-form ATTR=ID:source CONTENT=Modische<SP>Damen<SP>Ballerina<SP>Schuhe.<BR>Enthalten<SP>ist<SP>das<SP>abgebildete<SP>Modell,<SP>gemischt<SP>in<SP>verschieden<SP>Größen.<BR>Dieses<SP>Modell<SP>stammt<SP>aus<SP>der<SP>aktuellen<SP>Kollektion.<BR>Original<SP>verpackte<SP>Neuware.<BR>Jedes<SP>Paar<SP>im<SP>Original<SP>Karton.<BR><BR>1<SP>Verkaufseinheit:<SP>12<SP>Paar.<BR>Größen:<SP>36-41<SP>(gemischt).<BR>Farben<SP>wählbar:<SP>Schwarz,<SP>Grau,<SP>Beige.<BR><BR>Artikel-Nr-:<SP>A233-1_ul.<BR><BR>Preis<SP>je<SP>Paar:<SP>9,49<SP>EUR.<BR>Preis<SP>je<SP>Verkaufseinheit<SP>(12<SP>Paar):<SP>113,88<SP>EUR.<BR>
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ID:gt-form ATTR=ID:gt-submit
' Now extract the translated text 
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ID:gt-res-dir-ctr EXTRACT=TXTL
```

The extracted text that I get is without any line breaks.

Any solution to overcome this problem?

Windows 10 64 bit , firefox 38.0.5, and imacros addon 8.9.2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code seems to work as needed:

```
' ...
' Now extract the translated text
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=ID:result_box EXTRACT=HTM
SET !EXTRACT EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.replace(/<\\/*span(.*?)>/g, '');")
```